# creating valid email address strings (only left of @sign needed)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation, email

I am currently working on a project where I have to generate some email addresses on the fly in javascript, based on some generic strings with various characters.

Say i have a couple of group names:

```
var groupname1: "This is my first group";
var groupname2: "This.is.yet@another@!#¤%&/()     group";
```

I need to figure out which characters to strip from the names, so i can make them email-valid

```
function removeWeirdCharsAndReturnEmailAddress(name){
  var emailValidString = [DO REGEX/OTHER MAGIC HERE];
  return emailValidString + '@domain.org';
}
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Syntax

Comment: Either use a character class like `[a-z0-9?/&%$§"!]` or `\w` or `\S` plus a quantifier: `\S+`, `\w+`, etc.

Comment: /^[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+(\.[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+)*``

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: http://emailregex.com/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It will consider what's on the left of the '@' per your question and strip out non email body characters. The regex I've used isn't perfect. You can tailor it to your requirement:

```
function removeWeirdCharsAndReturnEmailAddress(name){
    var indexOfAt = name.indexOf("@");
    var s = '';
    if (indexOfAt > -1)
      s = str.substring(0, indexOfAt);
    else
      s='do something in case no @ in string';

    var acceptedString = '';
    for (var i = 0, len = s.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (isValidEmailCharacter(s[i])) acceptedString += s[i];
    }

      return acceptedString + '@domain.org';
  }

  function isValidEmailCharacter(s){
     var re = /[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]/;
     return re.test(s);
  }
```

Comment: It'd be good to have some reference about where the regexp in `isValidEmailCharacter()` comes from. But I'm pretty sure that an address like `-|.@domain.org` is not valid.

Comment: I came up with the reg exp...it's something that simply accepts single characters with a to z A to Z numbers and some allowed special characters. As mentioned,  it needs some work. Domain.Org is what the OP used in his question and is obviously just for demonstration's sake

Answer (score 0):

You can create valid emails with generator library.

Check [Chance.js](http://chancejs.com/#email).

Code is very simple:

```
chance.email({domain: 'example.com'})
=> 'giigjom@example.com'
```

Comment: That library doesn't seem to do what the OP is asking for (strip or transliterate a given string and use it for the local part).

Comment: You right, but he said he works on a project to generate emails. This library can help him in this job.